# Find t to have an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of $t$ is $$\langle p, q\rangle = \int_t^2 p(x) q(x) dx$$ an inner product on $V=P2$? I tried to use the properties of an inner product such that $\langle p(x),p(x) \rangle =0$ if and only if $p(x)=0$,
but the equation turned out to a mess and I could not find $t$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $t$ must be lesser than $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilinearity and symmetry should hold for any $t$. It remains to show positive definiteness. When is $$\int_{t}^2(p(x))^2dx$$ positive? The integrand is always positive, so it should be positive if...

And it should be greater than zero for all nonzero polynomials if...(use that a polynomial is zero in a neighborhood iff it is the zero polynomial)